# Customizing the DataView Webpart paging style

Tags: web-part, data-view-web-part, paging

I have configured a dataview webpart that refers the sharepoint list and would like to have a custom paging instead the OOB paging.

The paging style should look like the below:

Home 1 2 3 4 5 End

Home 2 3 4 5 6 End

please let me know if the style(something look like this is also fine) is already available somewhere from I can download or help me to construct a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people asking for this over and over again in the last few years, but I've never seen anyone complete it fully and post it. It's certainly possible with some inventive use of XSL.

For a better UX, also consider showing all the items with the DVWP and doing the paging client side with script. Obviously, this suggestion only makes sense if it will work for the list you have (number of items, especially).

Comment: it could be bit difficult to have it on the client side as it is a huge list. Looking for a clue to implement it on the server side by tweaking the XSL.

Comment: Ok, well as I said, lots of people seem to say they want it, but I haven't seen a good example.

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen it done with the CQWP: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part-paging/

Comment: It does not allow me to get the values from the Query String..I need that functionality too for column based Sorting..

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know that works similar to thae is the Search Paging web part.  I'm not sure if you could utilize that and extend it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Karthikeyan as Marc stated.
You could use a jquery plugin for this.You would just have to customize the list to fit in

e.g http://slidesjs.com/examples/simple/